# Meteor-postgres PACKAGE_DIRS

Tags: postgresql, meteor

I'm about to use meteor-postgres (https://meteor-postgres.readthedocs.io). As i can see it has it's own implementations of "accounts-password", "accounts-base", "accounts-ui" and mayby other packages. The package is not installed via Atmosphere but is git cloned and linked to node via env variable PACKAGE_DIRS.
Does Meteor packages in PACKAGE_DIRS directories have higher priority than packages installed by "meteor add ..."? Should i uninstall old packages (that are supposed to be used with Mongo) with the same names via "meteor remove ..." or not?

The official guide to meteor-postgres is very uninformative, if someone have any links describing usage of this package i will be very greatful!

Comment: Note that PACKAGE_DIRS is now renamed METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS to avoid naming conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Local packages will take precedence, but if you want to be sure, you can change the name of the package (change the author), so it will definitely take your version.

I create a packages directory inside my meteor project for locally modified packages, and I don't need to set PACKAGE_DIRS, as meteor finds them there anyway